# Unidirectional @OneToOne with @MapsId does not work with lazy loading

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, hibernate-mapping

I want to map a `@OneToOne` association using Hibernate 5.3.10 and JPA.

I know that the parent side of a `@OneToOne` association cannot be loaded lazily when not using bytecode enhancements.

In this case, I only want to map the client side and use `@MapsId` association which is suggested here: [Best way to map onetoone](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)

Here is my mapping on the Client side.
The parent side `CardEntity` has no mapping to the `DeviceType` at all.

```
public class DeviceType {

    @Id
    @Column( name = "PRODUCT_CARD_TYPE_ID" )
    private Long cardTypeId;

    ...

    @OneToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn( name = "PRODUCT_CARD_TYPE_ID" )
    private CardEntity card;

    ....
}
```

I give it an extra `@JoinColumn` because the KEY column in the `CardEntity` has a different name than `"PRODUCT_CARD_TYPE_ID"`.
See [Change Id Column](https://vladmihalcea.com/change-one-to-one-primary-key-column-jpa-hibernate/)

For this mapping, `LAZY` loading does not work. It always executes another statement to fetch the `CardEntity`. What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: `I give it an extra @JoinColumn because the KEY column in the CardEntity has a different name than "PRODUCT_CARD_TYPE_ID"` - this is not clear for me. The name in the `@JoinColumn` specify the foreign key column name in the `DeviceType` table. To specify the name of the column referenced by this foreign key column you should use `referencedColumnName` property.  Could you please share your ddl sql for DeviceType and CardEntity tables to make it clear.

Comment: Sorry i think i expressed myself wrong. When i do not use the @JoinCOlumn annotation hibernate uses "card_id_product_card_type_id" as column name of the primary key of the DeviceType. It will prefix the id column with card. Here is how it can be fixed https://vladmihalcea.com/change-one-to-one-primary-key-column-jpa-hibernate/

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is the [HHH-12842](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12842). The described approach perfectly works in the hibernate 5.4. But it does not work in the hibernate 5.3 branch.

Comment: hmm that could be the reason. It does not work for any onetoone relationship. Thanks, i will try to upgrade

Comment: I have the same problem (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61140887/hibernate-onetoone-between-pks-with-lazy-behaviour) and migrated to Hibernate 5.4.14.Final and still doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Edit: I changed my code to using @MapsId and it works fine, so I guess yours will work too.

Comment: @Faliorn I tested the mapping described in this question for hibernate 5.4 and it works fine.