# Hibernate OneToOne between PK's with lazy behaviour

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-one

I'm trying to achieve to have an entity called `MyEntity` along with another entity called `MyEntityInfo` using Hibernate 5.3.13.Final with annotations under Wildfly 18.

The idea is to have `MyEntity` store some commonly requested fields, and `MyEntityInfo` store some rarely requested fields. Both share the same primary key called SID (Long), and there is a FK from Info's SID to Entity's SID. There can be entities without info.

Normally you will not require the additional info. For example, I don't want the info entity to be fetched when I query my entity like this:

```
MyEntityImpl entity = em.find(MyEntityImpl.class, 1L);
```

However, when I run this code, I find that there's a second query, fetching the Info entity along the main one, as in an `EAGER` behaviour.

I'm mapping the relationship using `@OneToOne`. I've tried several combinations of `FetchType`, `optional` and `@LazyToOne`, but so far without success.

Here is the code for both MyEntity and MyEntityInfo classes (additional getters and setters removed):

MyEntity (ID generator is a custom sequence generator):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = MyEntityImpl.TABLE_NAME)
public class MyEntityImpl {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "TMP_MY_ENTITY";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "GEN_" +
            TABLE_NAME)
    @GenericGenerator(name = "GEN_" +
            TABLE_NAME, strategy = CoreIdGenerator.ID_GENERATOR, parameters = {
                    @Parameter(name = "tableName", value = TABLE_NAME) })
    @Column(name = "sid", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Long               sid;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "myEntity", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
    @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
    private MyEntityInfoImpl   info;

    @Column
    private String             field;
```

MyEntityInfo:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = MyEntityInfoImpl.TABLE_NAME)
public class MyEntityInfoImpl {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "TMP_MY_ENTITY_INFO";

    @Id
    @Column(name = "SID", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Long               sid;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "SID", referencedColumnName = "SID", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private MyEntityImpl       myEntity;

    @Column(name = "INFO_FIELD")
    private String             infoField;
```

I've tried this solution, but as I said, it didn't work for me:

[Hibernate lazy loading for reverse one to one workaround - how does this work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17155452/hibernate-lazy-loading-for-reverse-one-to-one-workaround-how-does-this-work)

I've managed to do something somewhat similar using `@OneToMany` and managing data manually, but that's not what I'd like to do. However, another alternatives and information on whether this can be achieved or not using `@OneToOne`, or the right design pattern to do this are also welcome.

PS: Database tables creation for SQL Server, in case you want to try it:

```
create table TMP_MY_ENTITY (SID NUMERIC(19,0) NOT NULL, FIELD VARCHAR(100));
go
ALTER TABLE TMP_MY_ENTITY ADD CONSTRAINT PK_TMP_MY_ENTITY PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (SID);
go

create table TMP_MY_ENTITY_INFO (SID NUMERIC(19,0) NOT NULL, INFO_FIELD VARCHAR(100));
go
ALTER TABLE TMP_MY_ENTITY_INFO ADD CONSTRAINT PK_TMP_MY_ENTITY_INFO PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (SID);
go

CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_TMP_MY_ENTITY START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 CACHE 20;

alter table TMP_MY_ENTITY_INFO add constraint FK_TMP_MY_ENT_INFO_MY_ENT FOREIGN KEY (SID) references TMP_MY_ENTITY(SID);
go

insert into TMP_MY_ENTITY(SID, FIELD) VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR SEQ_TMP_MY_ENTITY, 'Field 1');
insert into TMP_MY_ENTITY_INFO(SID, INFO_FIELD) VALUES ((SELECT MAX(SID) FROM TMP_MY_ENTITY), 'Info 1');

insert into TMP_MY_ENTITY(SID, FIELD) VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR SEQ_TMP_MY_ENTITY, 'Field 2');
insert into TMP_MY_ENTITY_INFO(SID, INFO_FIELD) VALUES ((SELECT MAX(SID) FROM TMP_MY_ENTITY), 'Info 2');

insert into TMP_MY_ENTITY(SID, FIELD) VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR SEQ_TMP_MY_ENTITY, 'Field 3 no info');

-- DELETE ALL

drop table TMP_MY_ENTITY_INFO;
drop table TMP_MY_ENTITY;
drop sequence SEQ_TMP_MY_ENTITY;
```

Comment: Hibernate 5.3 has a problem with lazy loading for  @OneToOne (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60597259/unidirectional-onetoone-with-mapsid-does-not-work-with-lazy-loading/))

Comment: Migrated to Wildfly 19 and Hibernate 5.4.14.Final and still get the same behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

After following @SternK link, and upgrading to Wildfly 19 and Hibernate 5.4.14, it finally worked by using `@MapsId`.

The right mapping to use is this:

MyEntity:

```
public class MyEntityImpl {

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "myEntity", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "SID")
    private MyEntityInfoImpl   info;
```

MyEntityInfo:

```
public class MyEntityInfoImpl {

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "SID", referencedColumnName = "SID", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private MyEntityImpl       myEntity;
```

Comment: have the same issue, but it doesn't work for me

Comment: In hibernate 6 this not working anymore. But in version is working